# I'm trying to understand why a piece of CSS/JS (for site css editing) works in two different ways depending on what I comment out

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, toggle

Following the method shown in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgFo3fxuUyA&t=375s), I was able to successfully edit the css of "google.com" and the pages from its' searches.

I managed to create a toggle function that somewhat works through some assistance on here, but the toggle only works when the google matching line is omitted and then applies the css changes to the extension popup and not the actual site. The code for the site-level changes still works but only when the all toggle code is omitted.

I've tried rearranging the functions to see if maybe the scripting was out of order but nothing made any noticeable difference. Then tried nesting the main function that creates the css effect into the toggle itself (sits outside the toggle and then called in by a different function name), but both would still apply only to the popup.

I did notice that once the toggle was on and the popup exited, upon returning to the popup, the toggle would be unchecked again. I added in options storage to see if that would solve the trick but still does not save css changes, just allowed it to save the state of the toggle. Also if the toggle is saved as checked, the css changes do not appear when opening the popup until turning it off and then back on.

Below is the current code within the extension

JS:

```
//Get the URL
const site = window.location.hostname

//Function to add custom CSS
let customStyle;
const Add_Custom_Style = (css) => {
  customStyle = document.createElement("style")
  document.head.appendChild(customStyle).innerHTML = css;
}
const Remove_Custom_Style = () => customStyle.remove();

//Function to change CSS
function changeCSS(){
    //Function for Google.com
    if (site.includes("google.com")){/*Commenting this line out allows the toggle to take effect.
                                       To have the site-level effect take place, leave this line as is
                                       and comment out the "function changeCSS()" line above it and all    
                                       code below the css string brackets.*/
        Add_Custom_Style(`
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Advent+Pro:wght@300&display=swap');

        * {
            font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif !important; 
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        a {
            color: #b0dff4 !important; 
            font-size: 140%;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
            color: #b0dff4 !important;
        }
        `)
    }
}

//***Toggle function on off
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("togBtn").addEventListener("change", function() {
        if(document.getElementById("togBtn").checked){
            changeCSS(site);
        }
        else{
            customStyle.remove();
        }
    });
};

// Saves options to chrome.storage
function saveOptions() {
    var cssOn = document.getElementById("togBtn").checked;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
  cssOn: cssOn
}, function() {
  // Update status to let user know options were saved.
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
  setTimeout(function() {
    status.textContent = '';
  }, 750);
    });
}

  // Restores select box and checkbox state using the preferences
  // stored in chrome.storage.
  function restoreOptions() {
      // Use default value
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
      cssOn: true
    }, function(items) {
        document.getElementById("togBtn").checked = items.cssOn;
    });
  }
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restoreOptions);
  document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',
      saveOptions);
```

The main error of concern is a null parameters on the toggle function (marked by ***)

I did try to see how the extension api "insertcss" would be able to apply to this but it was a bit beyond me at the moment.

Comment: It looks like your function declaration doesnt have any parameters declared, but when you go to call it, you call it with a parameter. Maybe that has something to do with differing behavior for when you comment out the entire function vs. just what's inside?

Comment: Put `console.log(site)` at the beginning of the function to see what it contains. It obviously doesn't have what you expect.

Comment: @CoreyBo arguments that are passed but don't exist in the parameter list are simply ignored.

Comment: @CoreyBo @Barmar After doing some editing to see where the code wasn't meshing right, it seems that when the toggle code was active, it was only active for the extension popup html, so locally right? If I wanted to make the toggle apply `document.head.appendChild(customStyle).innerHTML = css;`  to the website and not the popup,, what would be the correct way to go about this?